# Pass SQL data into HTML Email body on DMAIL

Tags: html, sql, email, sp-send-dbmail

I am currently setting up a stored procedure that send an automated email. I have got that working fine but the body of the email is HTML. I Have used the HTML code from the old system it was being ran on but I am having a problem with one bit. There is a line that says "Dear Mr Person" fro example. How do I get the result from my SQL query to pick up. Also bare in minds there will be multiple recipients going out on multiple emails so somehow I need to loop the process until all results in the query have had an email sent out.

The code from the old system picked it up abnd the snippet of the HTML is Below;

font-size: 14px;">Dear [#Title] [#Lastname#],

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify little bit. Are you passing row html to SP with recipient and send email with in the SP?

Comment: Abdul - I am trying to take Title and Last name from a query, then insert that into the HTML, then send that with DDMail via stored proc.  I have done everything regarding the stored procedure, just need the title and name from my SQL Table to show in the HTML output

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Replace function here if I understand your requirement correctly.

Like .

```
  Declare @SourceString nvarchar(500)
  Set @SourceString = 'Your raw html'

  Declare @Output nvarchar(500)

  Declare @Title nvarchar(500)
  Declare @Lastname nvarchar(500)

  select @Title = #Title , @Lastname=#Lastname from [Table] where #condition

  set @Output= 
  replace(replace(@SourceString,'[#Title]',@Title),'[#Lastname#]',@Lastname)

  select @Output
```